# SQL Column Names and Values

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2000, pivot

I need to turn this table:

```
RecID   Date        Time        FirstName   LastName
6       5/28/2013   9:50:07 AM  Jenny       Welhberg
```

Into this:

```
Column      Value
RecID       6
Date        5/28/2013
Time        9:50:07 AM
FirstName   Jenny
LastName    Welhberg
```

I have:

```
SELECT COLUMN_NAME
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE TABLE_NAME = 'tablename'

select * from tablename where recid=6
```

Also note that I am working on SQL Server 2000 for this report.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you have a problem, possibly.  The columns seems to have different types.

Let me ignore that.  Let me assume that they all have the same type.  In "2000" you don't have unpivot.  I think the fastest way is to do a cross join:

```
select cols.colname,
       (case when cols.colname = 'RecId' then RecId
             when cols.colname  = 'Date' then Date
             when cols.colname  = 'Time' then Time
             when cols.colname  = 'FirstName' then FirstName
             when cols.colname  = 'LastName' then LastName
        end) as Value
from t cross join
     (select 'RecID' as colname union all
      select 'Date' union all
      select 'Time' union all
      select 'FirstName' union all
      select 'LastName'
     ) cols
```

If the original types are not strings, then you might have to convert them.

Comment: This seemed to work, Thanks!

Note - 
Change "when cols" to "when colname"